# downcasting non-template base to non-type template child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14, downcast

I have a non-type template class `template<std::size_t N> Derived<N>` which derives from some non-template base class `Base`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    double some_value;

    // Some methods and variables that do not depend on N
    // I wish to keep these in a non-templated class

    virtual const size_t get_N() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(double value): some_value {value} {};
};

template <std::size_t N>
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    double some_other_value;

    // Some functions and variables, for which
    // the types and actions depend on N

    const size_t get_N() override
    {
        return N;
    }
    Derived(double value1, double value2): Base(value1), some_other_value {value2} {};
};
```

Now I have a function `call_by_base(Base& my_base)`, which only uses member variables/functions declared in `Base`. The only exception to this, is a call to `template<std::size_t N> void call_by_derived(Derived& my_derived)`. Since almost the entire function `call_by_base` is independent of the template parameter, I would prefer to keep this function non-templated.

I tried to achieve the above with implementations along the lines of:

```
template<std::size_t N>
void call_by_derived(Derived<N>& my_derived)
{
    std::cout << "in call_by_derived" << std::endl;
    // Methods that use the functions and variables in Derived.
}

void broken_call_by_base(Base& my_base)
{
    std::cout << "in call_by_base" << std::endl;

    // Manipulations independent of child
    // type Derived<N>

    auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<my_base.get_N()>&>(my_base);
    call_by_derived(derived);

    // Manipulations independent of child
    // type Derived<N>
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get `error: expression ‘Base::get_N’ is not a constant-expression`. I tried to resolve this error by trying to change different thing, both in my Base and Derived class. This was all without success.

I managed to get the following alternative to work:

```
void working_call_by_base(Base& my_base)
{
    std::cout << "in call_by_base" << std::endl;

    if(my_base.get_N()==2)
    {
        auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<2>&>(my_base);
        call_by_derived(derived);
    }
    if(my_base.get_N()==3)
    {
        auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<3>&>(my_base);
        call_by_derived(derived);
    }
}
```

This is however very tedious, especially when `N` can take on many more values. Is there any way to get a function along the lines of `broken_call_by_base` working? That is: How can I downcast a non-template `Base` to a non-type template `Derived<N>`?

ps. Only object of the `Derived<N>` type will be created. This is the code in `main` to test:

```
int main()
{
    Derived<3> test(1.0,2.0);
        working_call_by_base(test);
        broken_call_by_base(test);
        call_by_derived(test);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, except if you do a big switch and implement all options, it's not going to work. It's not very good to have a base method using the derived class type... So probably you want to have some virtual entry points that the derived class will implement properly.

Comment: The problem with that is that my `Derived` class contains some functions, for which the number of arguments depend on `N` (or equivalently on a `std::array<double, N> r`. As far as I know, I can not make these function virtual members of my `Base`.

Comment: Then you need to implement some kind of visitor pattern.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Even if you are able to use a visitor here, you have somewhere to define a list of all possible callable derived classes. It is not important to say it is a list of cast operations inside a switch/case block or defining a std::variant< typelist!!!>, where the typelist has to be the complete set of all types which the code can work on. So yes, visitor seams to be an option, but it still needs a list of all possible options in any way.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be best if you can use a `virtual` member function to avoid the `if`/`else` checks.
If that is not an option for some reason, use of a callback/plugin mechanism is the most appropriate.

1. You provide a mechanism in the `Base`-specific code base to allow other classes/functions/modules to register functions that are appropriate for the type they know about.
2. In the `Base`-specific code, you keep track of the registered functions using a key that is appropriate for `Base`.
3. In the `Base`-specific code, you check whether a function has been registered for the key. If it has, you call the function with the suitable arguments.
4. In the derived class specific code, you can `downcast` to the appropriate class. If the `downcast` succeeds, in most cases it should, you proceed to use the derived class.

This pattern strictly adheres to the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and is one of my favorite coding patterns.

In your case, the key is `N`.

Here's an example program that demonstrates the concept.

```
#include <iostream>

// Base.hpp
// #pragma once

#include <cstdint>

class Base
{
   public:
      double some_value;

      // Some methods and variables that do not depend on N
      // I wish to keep these in a non-templated class

      virtual const size_t get_N() = 0;
      virtual ~Base() = default;
      Base(double value): some_value {value} {};

      typedef void (*CallbackFunctionType1)(Base& b);
      static void registerCallback(std::size_t N, CallbackFunctionType1 f);

};

void call_by_base(Base& my_base);

// Base.cpp
#include <map>

namespace BaseNS
{
   using CallbackFunctionType1Map = std::map<std::size_t, Base::CallbackFunctionType1>;

   CallbackFunctionType1Map& getCallbackFunctionType1Map()
   {
      static CallbackFunctionType1Map theMap;
      return theMap;
   }
}

void Base::registerCallback(std::size_t N, CallbackFunctionType1 f)
{
   BaseNS::CallbackFunctionType1Map& theMap = BaseNS::getCallbackFunctionType1Map();
   theMap[N] = f;
}

void call_by_base(Base& my_base)
{
   std::cout << "In call_by_base" << std::endl;
   BaseNS::CallbackFunctionType1Map& theMap = BaseNS::getCallbackFunctionType1Map();
   BaseNS::CallbackFunctionType1Map::iterator iter = theMap.find(my_base.get_N());
   if ( iter != theMap.end() )
   {
      iter->second(my_base);
   }
}

// Derived.hpp
// #pragma once

template <std::size_t N>
class Derived: public Base
{
   public:

      double some_other_value;

      // Some functions and variables, for which
      // the types and actions depend on N

      const size_t get_N() override
      {
         return N;
      }

      Derived(double value1, double value2): Base(value1), some_other_value {value2} {};
};

// Derived.cpp
// Register call back functions for Derived.

namespace DerivedNS
{
   template <std::size_t N>
      void call_by_derived(Derived<N>& derived)
      {
         std::cout << "In call_by_derived<" << N << ">" << std::endl;
         // Use derived.
      }


   template <std::size_t N>
      void call_for_derived(Base& my_base)
      {
         Derived<N>* d_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived<N>*>(&my_base);
         if ( d_ptr != nullptr )
         {
            call_by_derived(*d_ptr);
         }
         else
         {
            // Error.
         }
      }

   bool registerCallbackFunctions()
   {
      // Register callbacks for as many values of N as needed.
      Base::registerCallback(1, call_for_derived<1>);
      Base::registerCallback(2, call_for_derived<2>);
      Base::registerCallback(3, call_for_derived<3>);
      Base::registerCallback(4, call_for_derived<4>);
      Base::registerCallback(5, call_for_derived<5>);
      return true;
   }

   bool dummy = registerCallbackFunctions();
}

int main()
{
   Derived<1> d1(0, 0);
   Derived<2> d2(0, 0);
   Derived<10> d3(0, 0);
   call_by_base(d1);
   call_by_base(d2);
   call_by_base(d3); // Does not go to call_by_derived.
}
```

Output:

```
In call_by_base
In call_by_derived<1>
In call_by_base
In call_by_derived<2>
In call_by_base
```

Comment: Wow, I do not feel bad that I did not came up myself with such a solution! I was hoping for some nice template magic... this seems to work, but I feel it is a bit over the top. On the other hand, it might be the only solution...